# Asking the user what size the array should be

Tags: java, arrays, average

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * Created by b00598439 on 30/09/2015.
 */
public class Assessment1 {




    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("Enter number 1 for arrays, 2 to use ArrayLists, or any other number to end the program");
        for (int i = 1; i<=2; i=>3; i++){


            answer[i] nextInt(); //Get integer entered, if different from 1 or 2, if any other number then quit
        }

        System.out.println("What size of array would you like?");

        int SIZE = in.nextInt();  //What size should the array be?
        int [] answer = new int[SIZE];           //Lets user read into the program

        System.out.println("The total of the numbers in the program is: " + answer);  //Gives total of numbers

        System.out.println("The average of the numbers in the program is: " + avg);



        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0) ;          //Calculating the average
```

I have been trying to get the code sorted to write to screen and follow on through for the size of the array.  I have to get the user to select an option 1, or option 2, if option 1 or 2 isn't chosen then I have to terminate the program.  I cannot even get the first part printing or working and this is what I have to do:
1) If the array option is chosen, the program should:
• Ask the user what the size of the array should be
• Let the user read in the numbers into the array 
 • Output the total of the numbers stored in the array
• Output the average of the numbers stored in the array

I have been sitting here for 4 hours and still getting nowhere

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What output/errors are you seeing?  The code you've posted doesn't compile, please include a [minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should at least make the code compile before posting, unless you have a *specific* question about a compile error, in which case you should have included the error message.

Comment: If that is your whole class, you're missing a curly brace to close the main function and another one to close the whole class

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I developed a little more the code. I put it inside a while loop... it goes back to the beginning and asks to again to enter the options... you enter any number other than 1 or 2 and you get out. I tested it and it works ok in the console. Just a comment.. you are getting the average in integer values... if you would like to get doubles then you have to use doubles and use nextDouble instead of nextInt. Hope that it helps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assessment{
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Scanner to get the initial number options
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Scanner to get numbers to sum
    Scanner numSc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declaration of variables and array
    int answer = 0; //You need int answer, don't need an array by now
    int numAnswer;
    int sum = 0;
    int average;

   // Loop the program 
   while (true){
     System.out.println("Enter number 1 for arrays, 2 for arraylists, any other to quit");

      // Using in Scanner to test for integer input
      if(in.hasNextInt()){

          // If there is an integer then give it to numAnswer
          numAnswer = in.nextInt();

          // What to do if the option is 1, 2 or other number
          switch(numAnswer)
          {
              case 1:
              case 2:
                  answer = numAnswer;
                  break;
              default:
                  System.exit(0); // Out of the program
          }
      } 

      // If answer variable got number 1
      if (answer == 1){
          // New Scanner to get the size of the array
          Scanner sizeSc = new Scanner(System.in); 

          System.out.println("Enter the size of the array: ");

          // Getting the size of the array with sizeSc Scanner          
          int size = sizeSc.nextInt();

          // Making a new array with the size of size variable 
          int[] inputNums = new int[size]; 

          // Looping to get input numbers
          for (int i = 0; i < inputNums.length; i++){  
              System.out.println("Enter a number in the array: ");

          //Getting the numbers from console with numSc Scanner
              inputNums[i] = numSc.nextInt(); 
              sum += inputNums[i]; //Getting the sum of each number
          }

          average = (sum/size);
          System.out.println("Sum of numbers: " + sum);
          System.out.println("Average of numbers: " + average);
          System.out.println(" ");
       } else {
          System.out.println("YOUR CODE TO THE LISTARRAY");
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Nelson Stevenson, thank you for the input.  I really do appreciate it.  This is the whole task setWith the aid of a menu system, the program should prompt a user to enter in a series of real numbers into an array or an ArrayList. The user should also have the choice to end the program.  
1) If the array option is chosen, the program should:  
• Ask the user what the size of the array should be  • Let the user read in the numbers into the array  • Output the total of the numbers stored in the array   • Output the average of the numbers stored in the array

Comment: In the second option (Array Lists) 2) If the ArrayList option is chosen, the program should:  
• Let the user read numbers in the ArrayList (the user can terminate this process by entering in -999)  • Output how many numbers were entered  • Output the total of the numbers stored in the ArrayList  • Output the average of the numbers stored in the ArrayList  
  
After each option has run, the program should then give the user the choice of choosing to enter numbers into an array, an ArrayList or ending the program

Comment: When I compile the program, it prints to screen but does not go further than Enter 1 for such and such.  Case 1 is set for Arrays and 2 is for Array Lists. for the If statement I have tried to compile:  if (answer[0] == 1); 

                    else (answer == 2);  (Or should it continue to select any other option to terminate the program??)

Comment: if (answer[0] == 1);
                    do System.out.println("You have selected Arrays");
                    
                    while ()      if (answer[0] == 1);
                    do System.out.println("You have selected Arrays");
                    
                    while (set Array.length);

Comment: When you get to this point: if(answer[0] ==1)  it won't be necessary to go for another option to detect the exit of the program, because that is detected in the step before (the switch sentence)...  now we are implementing the result of the switch... if you got to this point is because you didn't terminate the programm. If you terminated it you wouldn't be in the if part... in the switch I put a default case that means that any number instead of 1 or 2 entered in the console will mean the end of the program (System.exit(0)) and you just get out. Is that your question?

Comment: If you want your program to loop and get back to the menu... then you can put a While (true) loop before the first System.out.println("Enter 1 for arrays... etc. It will terminate only when you choose any other number when you get to the switch part.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways,I have done it in a simple way so you can understand the whole code step by step.By the way,you haven't explained what you want the program to do if option 2 was chosen.You can remove the option 2 by deleting the "case 2:".See the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Assessment1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
          int average,sum=0;
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          Scanner length = new Scanner(System.in);
          Scanner option = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter 1 for arrays, 2 to use ArrayLists, or any other number to end the program");
          int x=option.nextInt();
          switch(x){
          case 1:
          System.out.println("Input array size: ");
          int len=length.nextInt();
          int[] numbers = new int[len];
          for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
          {
              System.out.println("Please enter number");
              numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
              sum += numbers[i];
          }
          average=sum/len;
          System.out.println("Total sum of all numbers: "+sum);
          System.out.println("Average of all numbers: "+average);
          case 2:
              //insert your "ArrayList code here,you haven't explained what you     want here
          default:
              System.out.println("Program terminated.");
          }
}
}
```